# How to build a docker image using a dockerfile and windows cmd

Tags: dockerfile, docker-desktop

I am a "noob" in computer related stuff, but I need to get OWASP OWTF to work because I have to demonstrate it for some other students(short demo, basics).
Therefore I installed docker desktop on my windows computer and downloaded the OWTF repo( the whole, and the specified docker repo), but when I type "docker build -t  (path to dockerfile)" for either of the dockerfiles in the windows cmd, it says "system cannot find the file specified".
Dunno where I went worng or what my mistakes are, if anybody can help me to get it working that would be greatly appreciated.

tried some commands, files were not found

Comment: First of all, you have to build the image but your command is wrong, use instead `docker build -t owtf:auto -f /path/to/your/Dockerfile` Then you can run a container based on this image via `docker run --rm owtf:auto`